# how to check https using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect to a url with HttpUrlConnection. the host which user enter can be running on http:// or https://. when i am connecting it throws an exception as EOFException.
Is there any way that i identify that url is running on https through some error code or something ??

Following code i am using for this purpose.

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
```

I m using the abode code what if the url is not valid like i type wwww.gooooooodldldle.com
which is not valid url. I am getting Java.net.SocketTimeout exception here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL cannot change after the connection has been created if you don't reacreate it again. I would do it like this to know the protocol.

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(url[0]);
    if(url.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase(HTTPS){
        Lod.i(TAG, "Is HTTPS connection");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Is HTTP connection");
    }
} catch (EOFException eofEx) {
    eofEx.printStackTrace();
}
```

After update:

You can check the url string with a Regular Expresion and then if it's correct try the connection. Or put all the logic inside a try catch and show a toast or dialog if the exception is rised.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi 
i want to check if the host is not valid.As of now i am getting an exception.

Comment: @TarunSharma can you update your question and add you exception trace? That could be helpful.

Comment: Updated answer, try it. Either approach should work. I personally prefer the regular expresion over raising a Exception. Will try to update it again when I get home.

Comment: well i can not put a check if url is valid a url can be anything i want put check in catch block when exception occur & tell the user that url is not valid in that case i may get a request timeout or host unreachable exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't mind, try to use [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library instead